# Is there any way we can show an alert or popup near to the mouse pointer

Tags: javascript, canvas, charts, html5-canvas

I need to show the alert box ( custom popup ) near to the mouse pointer inside a canvas ( graph ).

> Any one can provide any idea on this. The tool tip already i have implemented but it can't contain a button and we cant select any item in a tool tip.
>
> > We are using chart.js for the graph view. I have added the click event and when we click on the graph, an alert box has been shown and on click of 'OK' some action is fired.
> >
> > > But we need to show the message near to the mouse pointer, Is there any work around for this?

Comment: 1)in handler for click event you can get mouse position ( from event object ). 2)So you should set for your alert-box position absolute ( for example ) and top/left position based on data from point 1

Comment: How can we set the alert box position?

Comment: you can set alert box position. but you write about custom popup ( usually it's just a div block ) so you can set its position by css

Comment: You could use the jQueryUI tooltip.  You can set its position relative to any document (the canvas).  Link:  http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#option-position

Comment: I have managed to use the bootstrap popover, and placed inside the canvas. that worked. Thanks for your response.